# mongos error "mirrored config server connections are not supported"

Tags: mongodb

Is something wrong with this?

```
  $ sudo mongos --logpath "mongos-1.log" --configdb localhost:57040,localhost:57041,localhost:57042 --fork
    FailedToParse: mirrored config server connections are not supported; for config server replica sets be sure to use the replica set connection string
    try 'mongos --help' for more information
```

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you just have to update your `--configdb to "repSetConfigName/localhost:57040,localhost:57041,localhost:57042"`

here is an example :

this is my configuration of the config server:

```
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg0 --replSet conf --port 27050 --fork --logpath log.cfg0 --logappend
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg1 --replSet conf --port 27051 --fork --logpath log.cfg1 --logappend
mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg2 --replSet conf --port 27052 --fork --logpath log.cfg2 --logappend
```

then I used

```
# connect to any of the mongod process on port 27050, 27051, 27052
mongo --port 27050

rs.initiate(
  {
    _id: "conf",
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
      { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27050" },
      { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27051" },
      { _id : 2, host : "localhost:27052" }
    ]
  }
)
```

fianlly

```
mongos --configdb "conf/localhost:27050,localhost:27051,localhost:27052" --fork --logpath log.mongos0 --port 27200
```

Answer (score 0):

Just appendix to @sylia-baraka answer... If you are using MongoDB 3.4 or newer you need to use CSRS instead of SCCC, read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/upgrade-config-servers-to-replica-set/).

> In version 3.4, MongoDB removes support for SCCC config servers. Before you can upgrade your sharded clusters to 3.4, you must convert your config servers from SCCC to CSRS. To convert to CSRS, follow the procedure to change your 3.2.x SCCC to 3.2.x CSRS.

Answer (score 0):

configdb should be like this :

> "your_replSetName/host:port,host:port,host:port"